# Pandas fillna value '2001-01-01T00:00:00Z' has dtype incompatible with datetime64[ns]

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, datetime64

Hi im a little bit stuck here, i'm trying to fill empty dates in a df.
This is my code:

```
change_date["latest_change_at"].fillna("2001-01-01T00:00:00Z", inplace=True)
```

This is my error:

> Value '2001-01-01T00:00:00Z' has dtype incompatible with datetime64[ns], please explicitly cast to a compatible dtype first.

I tried to change the values for the `fillna` to `datetime64[ns`] by running this:

```
change_date["latest_change_at"].fillna(np.datetime64('2001-01-01T00:00:00'), inplace=True)
```

> pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Cannot cast 2001-01-01 00:00:00 to unit='ns' without overflow.

> AssertionError: Did not expect new dtype datetime64[ns] to equal self.dtype datetime64[ns]. Please report a bug at https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues.

Comment: Seems like a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/55025). Try updating `pandas`

Answer (score 0):

The numpy syntax you shared works for me.

can you try this:

```
df["start_dt"].fillna(pd.to_datetime("2001-01-01",format="%Y-%m-%d"), inplace=True)
```